# Custom paths in Zend Framework 2 configuration

Tags: configuration, zend-framework2, relative-path

Hello Stack Overflow Community

I am having some problems with my custom paths in my zend framework 2 module.
I've added following code to my module.config.php :

```
// custom configuration
'custom' => array(
    'paths' => array(
        'pickUpDir' => '/var/www/beam/public/in/',
        'errorDir' => '/var/www/beam/public/error/',
        'temporaryDir' => '/var/www/beam/module/Beam/temp/',
        'archiveDir' => '/var/www/beam/module/Beam/archive/'
    )
),
```

Now this works fine on my virtual developement server but i want it to work universaly, meaning if i put my Zend Framework application on a live server which has a different folder structure it should still work.

Is there a way to declare relative paths or something like that ?
Many thankx in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The magic constant `__DIR__` will return the current directory which should be `/..../Yourmodel/config/`.

From there on you could just do:

```
'custom' => array(
    'paths' => array(
        'pickUpDir' => __DIR__ . '/../../public/in/',
        'errorDir' => __DIR__ . '/../../public/error/',
        //etc
    )
),
```

Comment: Thanks.that's the answer i was looking for :) Works perfectly

Answer (score 1):

Alternatively to cptnk's answer (which is also working), you can also use the get_cwd() function that will return you the root of your webapp, so that you can write stg like

```
'custom' => array(
    'paths' => array(
        'pickUpDir' => get_cwd() . '/public/in/',
        'errorDir' => get_cwd() . '/public/error/',
        //etc
    )
)
```

as ZF2 defines the current working directory as root of your project.

Comment: thanks for pointing that out I did not know about get_cwd() yet.

Comment: Yes thanks. I didn't know about that either. i gues cwd stands for current working directory ?

Comment: Yep cwd means current working directory. ZF2 set it up in this way so that you're sure to work in your application context